# Type Conversion/Casting Confusion in C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, casting, conversion-operator

What is *Type Conversion* and what is *Type Casting*?

When should I use each of them?

Detail: Sorry if this is an obvious question; I'm new to C++, coming from a ruby background and being used to `to_s` and `to_i` and the like.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Conversion** is when a value is, um, converted to a different type. The result is a value of the target type, and there are rules for what output value results from what input (of the source type).

For example:

```
int i = 3;
unsigned int j;
j = i; // the value of "i" is converted to "unsigned int".
```

The result is the `unsigned int` value that is equal to `i` modulo `UINT_MAX+1`, and this rule is part of the language. So, in this case the value (in English) is still "3", but it's an unsigned int value of 3, which is subtly different from a signed int value of 3.

Note that conversion happened automatically, we just used a signed int value in a position where an unsigned int value is required, and the language defines what that means without us actually saying that we're converting. That's called an "implicit conversion".

"**Casting**" is an explicit conversion.

For example:

```
unsigned int k = (unsigned int)i;
long l = long(i);
unsigned int m = static_cast<unsigned int>(i);
```

are all casts. Specifically, according to 5.4/2 of the standard, `k` uses a *cast-expression*, and according to 5.2.3/1, `l` uses an equivalent thing (except that I've used a different type). `m` uses a "type conversion operator" (`static_cast`), but other parts of the standard refer to those as "casts" too.

User-defined types can define "conversion functions" which provide specific rules for converting your type to another type, and single-arg constructors are used in conversions too:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    Foo(int b) : a(b) {}                   // single-arg constructor
    Foo(int b, int c) : a(b+c) {}          // two-arg constructor
    operator float () { return float(a); } // conversion function
};

Foo f(3,4);              // two-arg constructor
f = static_cast<Foo>(4); // conversion: single-arg constructor is called
float g = f;             // conversion: conversion function is called
```

Answer (score 4):

Classic casting (something like `(Bar)foo` in C, used in C++ with `reinterpret_cast<>`) is when the actual memory contents of a variable are assumed to be a variable of a different type.  Type conversion (ie. Boost's `lexical_cast<>` or other user-defined functions which convert types) is when some logic is performed to actually *convert* a variable from one type to another, like integer to a string, where some code runs to logically form a string out of a given integer.

There is also static and dynamic casting, which are used in inheritance, for instance, to force usage of a parent's member functions on a child's type (`dynamic_cast<>`), or vice-versa (`static_cast<>`).  Static casting also allows you to perform the typical "implicit" type conversion that occurs when you do something like:

```
float f = 3.14; 
int i = f; //float converted to int by dropping the fraction
```

which can be rewritten as:

```
float f = 3.14;
int i = static_cast<int>(f); //same thing
```

Comment: +1, but it should be noticed that this terminology is not strictly adhered to. Consider `int i; float f = static_cast<float>(i)` – by your logic (and I agree), this is a *conversion*, not a cast. C++ still uses `static_cast` (and yes, I’m aware that an implicit conversion would work here). In other words: you have given the semantically most meaningful distinction of the two terms. But C++ doesn’t follow this distinction.

Comment: Edited to clarify some things, hopefully I'm not spreading misinformation.

Comment: You seem to be saying that a *cast-expression* (5.4/2) is not a cast, but rather a conversion. This may be a useful definition of "cast" vs. "conversion" for programming languages in general, but it's not the definition of "cast" used in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, any expression has a type. when you use an expression of one type (say type S) in a context where a value of another type is required (say type D), the compiler tries to convert the expression from type S to type D. If such an implicit conversion doesn't exist, this results in an error. The word type cast is not standard but is the same as conversion.

E.G.

```
void f(int x){}

char c; 

f(c); //c is converted from char to int.
```

The conversions are ranked and you can google for `promotions vs. conversions` for more details.

There are 5 explicit cast operators in C++ `static_cast`, `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and `dynamic_cast`, and also the `C-style cast`

Comment: Wow, thanks guys, I wasn't expecting such great answers so rapidly, thanks!

Comment: @Ell: C++ tag is a busy one :)

Answer (score 2):

Type conversion is when you actually convert a type in another type, for example a string into an integer and vice-versa, a type casting is when the actual content of the memory isn't changed, but the compiler interpret it in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Type casting indicates you are treating a block of memory differently.

```
int i = 10;
int* ip = &i;
char* cp = reinterpret_cast<char*>(ip);
if ( *cp == 10 )  // Here, you are treating memory that was declared
{                 // as int to be char.
}
```

Type conversion indicates that you are converting a value from one type to another.

```
char c = 'A';
int i = c;  // This coverts a char to an int.
            // Memory used for c is independent of memory
            // used for i.
```