# Does C++ have an equivalent to boost::numeric_cast<DestType>(SourceType)?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, floating-point, integer-overflow

I am doing a bunch of applied-mathematics/signal-processing/algorithms C++ code.

I have enabled the `-Wconversion` compiler warning to catch issues like runtime conversion of numbers that are type `double` to type `int32_t`.

Obviously I am always concerned during these conversions because:

- loss of the numbers decimal value
- possible positive or negative overflow ("positive overflow" is when a double has a value greater than `INT32_MAX` and tries to store that value in the destination type (`int32_t` in this case))

Whenever I am concerned about such a conversion I usually use the one-liner check:

```
boost::numeric_cast<DestType>(SourceType)
```

However I would like to do the same thing without `boost`.

**Does straight C++ have an equivalent to `boost::numeric_cast<DestType>(SourceType)`?**

**If straight C++ does not have an equivalent, what would be a comparable non-`boost` implementation?**

I would think a somewhat comparable check would be basically a template function that has a single if statement to check the input parameter against positive or negative overflow (by using the `std::numeric_limits<DestType>` `::max()` and `::min()` and throws an exception).

Comment: No, there is no numeric cast in Standard Library. As for non-boost implementation, boost is open-source, you can take implementation from boost and use it as is.

Comment: Naturally, if you do take the implementation from boost and use it like @SergeyA suggests, you still need to comply with the open source license that Boost uses.

Comment: @SergeyA I checked the Boost implementation, and it's unfortunately not as simple as copying a header file.

Comment: That is "straight C++".  Presumably you meant _"C++ standard library"_.  It is still C++ even if it is in a third-party library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[As @SergeyA stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658182/does-c-have-an-equivalent-boostnumeric-castdesttypesourcetype#comment86325616_49658182), no the standard C++ spec does not currently have an equivalent to Boost's `boost::numeric_cast<typename Destination>(Source value)`.**

Here is a straight-forward implementation that uses only standard C++:

```
template<typename Dst, typename Src>
inline Dst numeric_cast(Src value)
{
    typedef std::numeric_limits<Dst> DstLim;
    typedef std::numeric_limits<Src> SrcLim;

    const bool positive_overflow_possible = DstLim::max() < SrcLim::max();
    const bool negative_overflow_possible =
            SrcLim::is_signed
            or
            (DstLim::lowest() > SrcLim::lowest());

    // unsigned <-- unsigned
    if((not DstLim::is_signed) and (not SrcLim::is_signed)) {
        if(positive_overflow_possible and (value > DstLim::max())) {
            throw std::overflow_error(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ +
                                      std::string(": positive overflow"));
        }
    }
    // unsigned <-- signed
    else if((not DstLim::is_signed) and SrcLim::is_signed) {
        if(positive_overflow_possible and (value > DstLim::max())) {
            throw std::overflow_error(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ +
                                      std::string(": positive overflow"));
        }
        else if(negative_overflow_possible and (value < 0)) {
            throw std::overflow_error(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ +
                                      std::string(": negative overflow"));
        }

    }
    // signed <-- unsigned
    else if(DstLim::is_signed and (not SrcLim::is_signed)) {
        if(positive_overflow_possible and (value > DstLim::max())) {
            throw std::overflow_error(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ +
                                      std::string(": positive overflow"));
        }
    }
    // signed <-- signed
    else if(DstLim::is_signed and SrcLim::is_signed) {
        if(positive_overflow_possible and (value > DstLim::max())) {
            throw std::overflow_error(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ +
                                      std::string(": positive overflow"));
        } else if(negative_overflow_possible and (value < DstLim::lowest())) {
            throw std::overflow_error(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ +
                                      std::string(": negative overflow"));
        }
    }

    // limits have been checked, therefore safe to cast
    return static_cast<Dst>(value);
}
```

notes:

- compiler is g++ version 4.8.5.
- compiler flags:

  - -std=c++0x
  - -O0
  - -g3
  - -pedantic
  - -pedantic-errors
  - -Wall
  - -Wextra
  - -Werror
  - -Wconversion
  - -c
  - -fmessage-length=0
  - -Wsign-conversion
  - -fPIC
  - -MMD
  - -MP
- for floating point types you can't use `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` but instead must use `std::numeric_limits<Dst>::lowest()` because `::min` returns is 1e-38 instead of a negative floating point value
- lots of the `std::numeric_limits` are const expressions and so the compiler will be able to greatly simplify this at compile time (i.e. N if statements will be reduced to one if-statement at compile time or none)

Comment: This compiles with -Wconversion in g++ as mentioned, but not in clang. See https://godbolt.org/z/MMaFny

Comment: In addition g++ > 4.8.5 can also warn due to `-Wsign-compare` which is added by `-Wall`.

Comment: Shouldn't `negative_overflow_possible` simply be `std::numeric_limits<Dst>::lowest() > std::numeric_limits<Src>::lowest()`? I don't understand the need for the `std::numeric_limits<Src>::is_signed or` part.

Comment: I think you meant **and** not **or**, so `negative_overflow_possible = std::numeric_limits<Src>::is_signed and ...`

I presume the `std::numeric_limits<Src>::is_signed and` part is intended for short-circuiting the evaluation of the following `std::numeric_limits<Dst>::lowest() > std::numeric_limits<Src>::lowest()` expression.

Comment: Unless I missed something, I also noticed that the four outer if..else if clauses are redundant. The logic can be greatly simplified.

Comment: @EmileCormier at the moment i can't verify whether your comments/edits are right or wrong because verifying would take more time that i have at the moment. at the very least i would have to find the code that runs all the test cases.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Your example was still useful as a starting point, and I thank you for it.

Comment: Were you able to simplify the code in the end ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct analog but you can do the range change easily with In C++20's [`std::in_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_range)

```cpp
if constexpr (std::in_range<Dst>(value)) {
    // ...
} else {
    throw std::range_error(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ ": out of range");
}
```

---

There's also [`std::cmp_*` in `intcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp) to do comparisons yourself. Note that `std::in_range` and `std::cmp_*` only allow you to check the range, not whether the value is representable in the target type or not, for example a large `uint64_t` value like `9'007'199'254'740'993` can be entirely in `double`'s range but not exactly representable by `double`. You'll need to check that manually if required

```cpp
if constexpr (std::cmp_greater(val, std::numeric_limits<Dst>::max()))
{
    throw std::overflow_error(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ ": overflow");
}
else if constexpr (std::cmp_less(val, std::numeric_limits<Dst>::min()))
{
    throw std::underflow_error(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ ": underflow");
}
else
{
    auto value = static_cast<Dst>(val);
    if (value != val)
        throw std::domain_error("in-range value not representable in Dst");
    else
        // Do something with `value`
}
```