# Why should I use 'static_cast' for numeric casts in C++?

Tags: c++, casting

Sometimes, we need to explicitly cast one numeric type to another (e.g. to avoid warning when we lose precision or range). For some:

```
double foo;
```

we could write:

```
(float)foo
```

but most C++ programmers say it's evil 'old-style cast' and you should use the 'new-style cast':

```
static_cast<float>(foo)
```

There is an alternative of `boost::numeric_cast` which is quite interesting (at least in not-performance-critical code) but this question is about `static_cast`.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497016/best-practice-in-c-for-casting-between-number-types) was already asked, but the most important arguments used there are not valid for numerical cast (in my opinion, am I wrong?). There are they:

**You have to explicitly tell the compiler what you want to do. Is it upcast, or downcast? Maybe reinterpret cast?**

No. It is simple numeric cast. There is no ambiguity. If I know how `static_cast<float>` works, I know how does it work for 'old-style' cast.

**When you write `(T)foo` you don't know what `T` is!**

I'm not writting `(T)foo` but `(float)foo`. I know what is `float`.

Are there any important reasons for using a new, better casts for numeric types?

Comment: Consistency is one reason. Also, I'm of the opinion casts should stand out as much as possible. I've also seen `#define STATIC_CAST(To,From) ((To)From)` in the wild once in a C code base. But it mattered to those devs far more than it did to me.

Comment: Also, it's easier to textually search for casts. `(float)` can be part of function signature, opposed to `static_cast<float>(`

Comment: something like `(int)p;` will work fine as long as `p` is some number, however if `p` is actually a pointer to some number use of C-style cast will cause you to shot your own leg. Note that `static_cast` is a rather weak alternative so some projects are using even stricter casts that can express intent of value truncation / sign change and other things.

Answer (score 1):

In a general scenario (which you have mentioned) you'd want explicit C++ cast to avoid possible issues mentioned in [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used) (ability to devolve into `reinterpret_cast`).

In numeric scenario you get two benefits at least:

- you don't need to remember that C-style cast for numerics safely devolves to `static_cast` and never reaches `reinterpret_cast` - I'd call it "ease of use" and "no surprises" part
- you can textually search for cast operations (`grep 'static_cast<double>'` vs `grep '(double)'` which can be part of function signature)

Answer (score 1):

Like many things inherited from C, the more specific C++ variants are there to inform *readers* of the code, *not* the compiler.

You use `static_cast<double>` because it **doesn't** do all the things that `(double)` can.

> The conversions performed by
>
> - a `const_­cast`,
> - a `static_­cast`,
> - a `static_­cast` followed by a `const_­cast`,
> - a `reinterpret_­cast`, or
> - a `reinterpret_­cast` followed by a `const_­cast`,
>
> can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion.

[[`expr.cast/4`]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.cast)

Specifying `static_cast` alerts you with a compile time error, rather than silently having undefined behaviour, if the expression you *think* is safe *isn't*.

Comment: Can `(double)` do a `reinterpret cast`? How?

Comment: @M.M `reinterpter_cast` from pointer to floating point types is not allowed, so C-style cast is not allowed either

Comment: OK. But even so, this is a specific case of a general rule to avoid C-style casts for the reasons given

Comment: @peper0 doesn't matter. `(double*)` *does*, and you should be consistent as to how you write casts. Like many things inherited from C, the *more specific* C++ variants are there to inform *readers* of the code, not the compiler