# Why the means are different when appending items to np.array and a list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a code which looks like this:

```
list_a = []
arr = np.array([])
for _ in range(1,101):
    list_a.append(np.random.randint(1,1001,100).mean())
    arr = np.append(arr, np.random.randint(1,1001,100).mean())

print(f'casted list to np.array mean - {np.array(list_a).mean()}')
print(f'old school average - {sum(list_a)/len(list_a)}')
print(f'just arr.mean - {arr.mean()}')
print(f'first array element - {arr[0]}')
print(f'first list element - {list_a[0]}')
print(f'last arr element - {arr[99]}')
print(f'last list element - {list_a[99]}')
```

This prints:

```
casted list to np.array mean - 498.9785
old school average - 498.97850000000005
just arr.mean - 499.5889000000001
first array element - 510.76
first list element - 518.8
last arr element - 527.54
last list element - 521.58
```

Why do I get means that are not equal and why does the first and the last elements ( I am assuming the rest too ) are not equal when they are inside the same loop? Is there a difference when casting list to np.array and getting the mean vs just appending items to a np.array and getting the mean?

Comment: why do you *expect* these to be exactly the same? They are random... That is, you create two random numbers on each iteration: `np.random.randint(1,1001,100).mean()`. These means will be slightly different. hence the slightly different outcomes... Just create *one* and use that value for both approaches. Note, **you really shouldn't use `numpy.append` this way. It is highly inefficient. As your N grows, this will become slow

Comment: ..., thank you, I dont know how I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I get means that are not equal

Because the data is different, as you found with the other tests.

> and why does the first and the last elements ( I am assuming the rest too ) are not equal when they are inside the same loop?

Because each time through the loop, you do `np.random.randint(1,1001,100).mean()` to determine a value to append to `list_a`, and then you do it *again* to determine a value to append to `arr`. `np.random.randint` is used to produce random numbers, so of course it produces a different array on each of those two calls; and so the means are different, and so the values stored are different.

> Is there a difference when casting list to np.array and getting the mean vs just appending items to a np.array and getting the mean?

There is no such thing in Python as "casting", but no, you get the same value this way. I know, your output shows `498.9785` in one case and `498.97850000000005` in another. These are extremely close. Floating-point work sometimes involves a tiny amount of imprecision.

Comment: That last part is misleading. The difference is most likely caused by display preferences than actual differences in the data.

Comment: There are a different number of decimals shown all over the place in OP's reported data, which made me doubt that explanation. I also don't know the details on what causes Python to show differing amounts of precision for float values, aside of course from explicitly specifying it in the format string.

Comment: Numpy arrays and python floats have a different `repr`. That being said, I see your point.

Comment: Thank you, my bad on missing such an obvious answer. Not sure why you say that there is no such thing as casting in python, I assume casting is simply converting one data type to another.

Comment: Well, not everyone uses exactly the same definitions, but I'm thinking of it along the same basic lines as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337306/type-conversion-casting-confusion-in-c .

Answer (score 0):

np.random.randint() generates a new number every time you call it so it makes sense the numbers in both lists are different. If you want to add the same number to both lists, store it in a variable first and then append it to both lists:

```
list_a = []
arr = np.array([])
for _ in range(1,101):
    value = np.random.randint(1,1001,100).mean()
    list_a.append(value)
    arr = np.append(arr, value)

print(f'casted list to np.array mean - {np.array(list_a).mean()}')
print(f'old school average - {sum(list_a)/len(list_a)}')
print(f'just arr.mean - {arr.mean()}')
print(f'first array element - {arr[0]}')
print(f'first list element - {list_a[0]}')
print(f'last arr element - {arr[99]}')
print(f'last list element - {list_a[99]}')
```

The difference between the first two averages is a difference in representation by the print() function, the values themselves only differ by 0.000000000000005.