# difference between type conversion and type casting?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between casting and conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166840/what-is-the-difference-between-casting-and-conversion)

difference between type conversion and type casting?
ii will be better if you make it by an example..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, this is a duplicate of

[What is the difference between casting and conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166840/what-is-the-difference-between-casting-and-conversion)

which was inspired by

[What is the (type) in (type)objectname.var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166349/what-is-the-type-in-typeobjectname-var)

I would read those first, and then come back to this brief summary.

I refer you to the first paragraph of chapter 6 of the specification, which states:

> A conversion enables an expression to
>   be treated as being of a particular
>   type. A conversion may cause an
>   expression of a given type to be
>   treated as having a different type, or
>   it may cause an expression without a
>   type to get a type. Conversions can be
>   implicit or explicit, and this
>   determines whether an explicit cast is
>   required. For instance, the conversion
>   from type int to type long is
>   implicit, so expressions of type int
>   can implicitly be treated as type
>   long. The opposite conversion, from
>   type long to type int, is explicit and
>   so an explicit cast is required.

What do we learn from this?

- A *conversion* is a *semantic operation* on two operands: *expression* and a *type*.
- The exact operation determined by the semantic analysis determines how the actual value is converted at runtime.
- A *cast* is a *syntactic element* of the C# language of the form `(type)expression` which explicitly induces a *conversion* from the expression to the type.

These are just a few of the *implicit* conversions you can do in C#:

```
short aa = 123;      // numeric constant conversion from int to short
int bb = aa;         // numeric conversion from short to int
int? cc = null;      // nullable conversion from null literal to nullable int.
object dd = "hello"; // implicit reference conversion from string to object
IEnumerable<Giraffe> ee = new Giraffe[] { new Giraffe() } ;
                     // implicit reference conversion from array to sequence
IEnumerable<Animal> ff = ee; 
                     // implicit reference conversion involving array covariance
ff = null;           // implicit reference conversion from null literal to sequence
bb = 456;            // implicit identity conversion from int to int
dd = bb;             // implicit boxing conversion from int to object
Func<int, int> gg = x=>x+x; 
                     // anonymous function to delegate type conversion
```

*Explicit* conversions usually, but not always, require a cast:

```
aa = (short)bb;      // explicit numeric conversion
string hh = (string)dd; //explicit reference conversion
```

And so on.

It is *legal* to use a cast for an implicit conversion but usually not necessary.

Is that clear? The key point is that *a conversion is a semantic operation* which leads to *an action at runtime* and *a cast is a syntactic element that tells the compiler to analyze a conversion using the explicit conversion analysis rules*.

If the subject of conversion logic interests you then you might be interested in my articles on the subject, which are here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/conversions/

Comment: "Explicit conversions usually, but not always, require a cast": could you give an  example where a cast is not required ? Off the top of my head I can't think of any...

Comment: @Thomas: foreach(Giraffe g in animals) induces an explicit conversion from Animal to Giraffe with no cast. byte b = 1; b += 2; induces an explicit conversion from int to byte; this is analyzed as b = (byte)((int)b+(int)1)). A cast which is a user-defined explicit conversion may introduce a built-in explicit conversion on "either side" of the operand; in that case we do have a cast in the source code but it can cause up to three explicit conversions to actually execute.

Comment: There are also obscure interop scenarios in which the compiler will insert an explicit conversion from interface to class on your behalf.

Comment: thanks for the examples. Very interesting answer by the way !

Answer (score 2):

Conversion = actually transforming an object into an instance of a different class
ex:

```
int i = 3; 
string str = i.ToString();
```

Transforms an integer into a string

Casting = forcing the type of an object because you know more than the compiler
ex:

```
object obj = 3;
int i = (int)obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/266654-casting-vs-using-convert-methods)'s a good thread with some examples and answers to your question.